# Is vector size more than 2147483647 in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<int> large(2147483648, 0);
```

has an error. However, I know there is no limit of vector size in C++.

Comment: What the error is?

Comment: from where do you know that there is no limit? Nice hardware you must have ;)

Comment: There **is** limit unfortunately. Welcome to **StackOverflow**!

Comment: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error, located in memory 0x006FF754 shown in VS2015

Comment: You can check the max. element count for particular vector by calling `std::vector<>::max_size()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size

Comment: *I know there is no limit of vector size in C++.*  How do you know this?

Comment: Of course there are limits. First of all given by the extent of the possible values of `std::vector<int>::size_type`, which is typically `std::size_t`. In practice, the limits are given by the maximum contiguous chunk of virtual memory you heap is actually able to allocate.

Comment: How much memory does your computer have?  And how large a vector did you ask to create?

Comment: There is no hard limit imposed by the C++ standard, that does not mean however, that there is no limit. Many computational problems would be much easier to solve with unlimited memory. And it would drastically reduce the amount of people attempting to download more ram.

Comment: @George _There is no hard limit imposed by the C++ standard_ - I don't agree. The size parameter of the vector's constructor is of type `std::vector<T>::size_type`. That type itself imposes a limit on the size (it's implementation-defined, but it's there).

Comment: In fact there are a number of limits. As well as the use of `size_type`, usually `size_t` having a maximum number, c++11 std::vector also has a `max_size()` method which describes any computational limit there may be below the capacity of `size_t`. This is usually the capacity of size_t (or ssize_t) divided by the object size. However, this is still theoretical, and you should expect to get a memory exhaustion error before that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum vector size is 64-bit unsigned integer, which is unlimited in practice. But you are using 32-bit integer literals. Try adding the suffix 'ull' after the digits to get 64 bit literal.

```
std::vector<int> large(50000000000ull, 0);
```

Comment: _Maximum vector size is 64-bit unsigned integer_ - That's not correct. Maximum size is given by `std::vector<T>::size_type`, which is implementation-defined (on 64-bit system, it's likely 64-bit unsigned integer). See http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-2.

Comment: BTW, the type of an integer literal is `long` or even `long long` if the value cannot be represented by `int`: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.icon-2.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, you are right for both things.

Comment: @Bathsheba, you are right - I worked several years on Java an there is why I made that mistake. I even was upset from this behavior in Java, but It seems I have forgotten that fact.

Comment: @SimoSimov: Java does bad things to you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of kind replies. I know there is a limit for vector size. If I choose x86 as compile environment in VS2015, I get the *max_size* of vector is 1073741823 which is less than choosing X64 as environment. Thank you!